Handle click on MenuBarExtra's icon without opening menu
Is there a way for MenuBarExtra to handle click on the icon and perform some action, without opening a view?
I know it's possible with NSStatusItem, but I already have other MenuBarExtra items that I would like to keep an order (doesn't seem like there is a way to reorder them either).

Here is a rather convoluted way to do this. Use a .window style menu bar extra, and use a NSViewControllerRepresentable as the window's content.
In the NSViewController, you can override viewWillAppear to detect the click. Then dismiss the window immediately.
struct MyView: NSViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    let onClick: () -> Void
    
    class ChangeDetector: NSViewController {
        var dismiss: DismissAction?
        var onClick: (() -> Void)?
        
        override func viewWillAppear() {
            super.viewWillAppear()
            onClick?()
            Task {
                dismiss?()
            }
        }

        override func loadView() {
            self.view = NSView()
        }
    }
    
    func makeNSViewController(context: Context) -> ChangeDetector {
        let detector = ChangeDetector()
        return detector
    }
    
    func updateNSViewController(_ nsView: ChangeDetector, context: Context) {
        nsView.dismiss = dismiss
        nsView.onClick = onClick
    }
}

MenuBarExtra("Some title", systemImage: "circle.fill") {
    MyView() {
        print("Clicked!")
    }
}
.menuBarExtraStyle(.window)

As for ordering NSStatusItems, note that the user can manually drag the status items while holding down the command key to reorder them.

Thanks for the code snippet. It looks like it would work, but clicking on it throws an exception about not being able to find the nibName ChangeDetector. Does it work on your end?

@JamesZZZ It worked on my end. Perhaps try overriding loadView.

That worked, I added self.view = NSView() inside loadView and the exception is no longer thrown that click was handled.
